# Is it possible to refresh program files in JavaFX while an instance is running?

Tags: file, javafx, copy, nio, filechooser

I am building an inventory management system and have created a button which opens a new FXML for entering a new item into the database. I have created the ability to add an image and it updates the image column of the database with the URL and when I click save, it saves copies the image from the source location to the target location (which is a package in the program). If I save and close the program then I can refresh the project in eclipse, log back into the program and the newly added item will show in the tableView populated from the database without any issue.

The problem I have is that when I click the save button I would like it to 'refresh' the programs files and packages so when I query the parts database it will show the newly added parts and not throw me an error for not seeing the image in the image package that I created (it shows in there when program is closed and refreshed). Is it possible to refresh these image packages with code? Should the images be stored in an external file instead? If not, is it possible to save images to the program packages without having to use the absolute path?

The code I have so far is:

```
// Event Listener on Button[#saveItemBtn].onAction
@FXML
public void saveNewItemClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
        this.dbState = (String) databaseChoiceBox.getValue();

        DBConnection dBC = new DBConnection();
        con = dBC.getDBConnection();
        String maxSQL = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM " + dbState + "_parts_list";
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(maxSQL);

        int idNumber = rs.getInt(1);
        idNumber++;

        quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityTxt.getText());
        min = Integer.parseInt(minTxt.getText());
        max = Integer.parseInt(maxTxt.getText());


        double price = Double.parseDouble(priceTxt.getText());
        SelectedItem selectedItem = new SelectedItem();
        selectedItem.setId(idNumber);
        selectedItem.setQuantity(quantity);
        selectedItem.setMin(min);
        selectedItem.setMax(max);
        selectedItem.setEquipment_id(equipmentIDTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setEquipment_group(equipmentGroupTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setPrice(price);
        selectedItem.setManufacturer_name(manufacturerNameTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setModel_number(modelNumberTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setVendor_name(vendorNameTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setVendor_part_number(vendorPartNumberTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setTolmar_part_number(tolmarPartNumberTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setDescription(descriptionTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setAdditional_notes(additionalNotesTxt.getText());
        selectedItem.setPart_location(locationTxt.getText());
        if (img != null) {
            selectedItem.setImage("/" + dbState + "Images/" + imagePath);   
        } else {
            selectedItem.setImage("/img/NoImageFound.png");
        }
        selectedItem.setDepartment(databaseChoiceBox.getValue().toLowerCase());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + dbState + "_parts_list VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement myStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        myStmt.setInt(1, idNumber);
        myStmt.setString(2, selectedItem.getManufacturer_name());
        myStmt.setString(3, selectedItem.getModel_number());
        myStmt.setString(4, selectedItem.getVendor_name());
        myStmt.setString(5, selectedItem.getVendor_part_number());
        myStmt.setString(6, selectedItem.getTolmar_part_number());
        myStmt.setString(7, selectedItem.getPart_location());
        myStmt.setDouble(8, selectedItem.getPrice());
        myStmt.setInt(9, selectedItem.getQuantity());
        myStmt.setInt(10, selectedItem.getMin());
        myStmt.setInt(11, selectedItem.getMax());
        myStmt.setString(12, selectedItem.getImage());
        myStmt.setString(13, selectedItem.getEquipment_group());
        myStmt.setString(14, selectedItem.getEquipment_id());
        myStmt.setString(15, selectedItem.getAdditional_notes());
        myStmt.setString(16, selectedItem.getDescription());
        myStmt.setString(17, selectedItem.getDepartment());
        myStmt.executeUpdate();
        saveStatusLbl.setText("New Item Saved");
        Path source = Paths.get(img);
        Path target = Paths.get("E:/Programming/workspace/Inventory Management System 4/src/" + dbState + "Images/", file.getName());
        try {
            //replace existing file using java nio package
            Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        con.close();
        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        delay.setOnFinished( e -> window.close() );
        delay.play();

        }catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println(exc);
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

Comment: technically I do not need to  close the program. I have been able to click on my IDE and F5 to refresh and I can see the saved image pop up in my package, go back to the program and it does not error and shows the new item in tableView. I am just wondering if there is code to do this when I click the save button.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not store your data files among your class files. In a real-world scenario where you have bundled your application this would not work anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you know of any good resources for how this is normally done? I haven't had much luck looking on the internet and am probably not asking the right question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid modifying the resources of a application while you're running it.

Of course you could try to make it work by playing around with `ClassLoader`s e.g. use [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html), but IMHO it's much simpler to not store the files as resources, but to store them in a directory not inside the class path and access those files instead. You can get a URL string from a `Path p` by using:

```
p.toUri().toURL().toExternalForm()
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I will have to do more research on storing files for a program. In the database I have the url to point to where the images are. I am not quite sure how to point to the images the same way every time if the program could be saved anywhere on any drive and I would have to store the images in a specific location on a drive at work and have the hard code written to point there? How is this normally done? do you have a link that could point me in the right direction of how information like this is best stored, I haven't had much luck looking myself. Thanks!